# Incorrect splitOn error

Tags: c#, dynamic, dapper

There seems to be a problem with Dapper throwing an incorrect 'splitOn' error message in certain situations. I've come across a query that is not using Dapper multi-mapping, yet is throwing this error. During debugging it would appear that GetTypeDeserializer() runs on the query and if it detects no fields in the returned data it will incorrectly throw this error.

```
if (reader.FieldCount <= startBound)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id", "splitOn");
}
```

Commenting out this section fixes the problem, and Dapper continues to function normally. Is this a known problem, and is there a better fix?

The SQL in question goes something like:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (Id INT, Something BIT);
INSERT INTO @Temp SELECT Id, Something from Table;
WITH CTE AS (

  SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable mt LEFT JOIN @Temp t ON t.Id=mt.Id;

) SELECT CTE.* FROM CTE LEFT JOIN dbo.AnotherTable at ON at.Id=CTE.Id;
```

When I run the query, probably due to the query setup there are no columns returned in the dataset when the data does not exist. My example might not show this well, but the actual query is quite long and this is the behavior.

Comment: This makes sense to me.  If you select * from an empty set, it will return nothing.  You need to specify the columns if you want them to return every time, I believe.

Comment: But returning nothing (empty DTO object) is what should happen, not having Dapper throw an invalid exception.

Comment: @Codeman, I'm having the same issue even specifying all column names. And I agree with Michael, throwing an exception isn't as expected as just returning nothing.